# how to resolve popup center screen Div class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with class `.popup`. I have an iFrame used to open another image gallery, but when I show the popup using jQuery it isn't centered and the top most page element.

**CSS**

```
.popup {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:inherit;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height:400px;  
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup " style="display: none">
    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <input onclick='SelectImage(inputImage)' class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-left" type="button" value=" بازگشت " />
        <input id="btnImageSelect" onclick='SelectImage(inputImage)' class="btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" value="تایید عکس" />
    </div>
    <iframe id="iframeImage" src="../filemanager/ImagePicker.aspx" width="100%" height="320" frameborder="1"></iframe>
</div>
```

How do I fix this problem and where is my lost code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width  = $(.popup).width();
  var height  = $(.popup).height();
  $(".popup").css({"top":"50%", "left":"50%", "margin-top":height/2+"px", margin-left:width/2+"px"});   
});
```

This will move the `div` in center.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for with `width: inherit`. This will always make your popup as wide as its parent element, so there's no need for centering. With `position: absolute`, however, your popup will be positioned according to either the `body` element of your page, or a parent element with `position: relative`.

Here's what I'd do if I understand your problem correctly:

I'm assuming `width` is unknown here.

```
.popup {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugys4znt/

If you want the popup to stay on screen even when the user scrolls, use `position: fixed`.

Please specify some more what you're trying to achieve with `width: inherit`, and I'll get back to you.